# Poetry installation fails on Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, bash, python, python3

I am trying to [install poetry the recommended way](https://python-poetry.org/docs/#osx--linux--bashonwindows-install-instructions) on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS:

```bsh
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-poetry/poetry/master/get-poetry.py | python -
```

When I do so, it says:

```bsh
content.com/python-poetry/poetry/master/get-poetry.py | python -

Command 'python' not found, did you mean:

  command 'python3' from deb python3
  command 'python' from deb python-is-python3

curl: (23) Failed writing body (485 != 1378)
```

Then I try python3

```bsh
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-poetry/poetry/master/get-poetry.py | python3 -
```

The installation succeeds.

Afterwards when calling `poetry --version` to test the installation, I get:

```bsh
poetry: command not found
```

Although I added poetry to PATH manually, in `.bash_profile`:

```bsh
PATH=$PATH:~/poetry/bin
```

I also tried adding poetry to path in `.bashrc` similarly to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/60219/1548517):

```bsh
export PATH="~/poetry/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: you add `PATH=$PATH:~/poetry/bin` to path, but the path is `~/.poetry/bin`!

Comment: Thanks @pLumo, that worked. What a useless question I asked.

Comment: @pLumo Consider writing it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add `~/poetry/bin` to `PATH`, but it should be `~/.poetry/bin`.

---

Regarding `python` is not available, you can (re)install `python-is-python3` package via `apt`:

```
sudo apt install python-is-python3
```

Comment: "add a symlink manually" will be out of the APT control. Suggesting to remove this recommendation from answer.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of posterity, the old approach the OP mentions to installing Poetry [has been deprecated](https://python-poetry.org/docs/#installing-with-the-official-installer).  As of 22 Sep 2022, they recommend using the following command for Linux:

```
curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 -
```

I used this on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS and everything went smoothly.